QML Repeater3D rendering very slow
The Repeater3D type is used to create a large number of similar items. But if I try to fill the model with big amount of data it works slow. For example I have list with 500x500 items:
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

QList<QObject*> dataList;

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
        dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 1:", 1, j * 8, i * 8, 1));
    }
}

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));

I set this list as model in Repeater3d:
Repeater3D {
    id: _3DRepeater
    model: myModel
    Model {
        id: sphere
        x: model.modelData.x
        y: model.modelData.y
        z: model.modelData.z
        source: "#Sphere"
        scale.z: model.modelData.radius * 0.05
        scale.y: model.modelData.radius * 0.05
        scale.x: model.modelData.radius * 0.05
        materials: principledMaterial
    }
}

This is DataObject class:
class DataObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int radius READ radius WRITE setRadius NOTIFY radiusChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int x READ x WRITE setX NOTIFY xChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int y READ y WRITE setY NOTIFY yChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int z READ z WRITE setZ NOTIFY zChanged)

public:
    DataObject (const QString& name, int radius, int x, int y, int z) : m_name(name), m_radius(radius), m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z) {};
    ...
private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_radius;
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    int m_z;
};


The list has 500x500 items per example above.

@AlexanderV yes. Anyway we have only one object for rendering and many copies of it. Right?

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/quick3d-instancing.html

From the link shared above: "Instancing allows duplicating a model with variations. In contrast to using a Repeater3D, the model and its graphics resources are only allocated once. The rendering of the duplicated instances is done at a low level by the GPU. Depending on the complexity of the model, this can give a performance improvement of several orders of magnitude."
